# Do I need to manually create a bottle?

Tags: homebrew

I'm in the process of creating a formula to submit to `homebrew-core` and I see the documentation describes the process of creating a bottle. However what's not clear to me is: do I need to create it myself? Or will the system automatically generate and add them to the formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However what's not clear to me is: do I need to create it myself?

No, you do not need to create bottles yourself. In fact, you can't; only the Homebrew maintainers can upload bottles.

After your formula has been accepted, BrewTestBot (a bot operated by the Homebrew project) will build bottles if appropriate and add them to the formula automatically. You don't need to do anything special.